# Limit access to Web Service to approve Clients (Javascript) similar to Bing/Google Map API keys

Tags: javascript, java, web-services, security, web-scraping

I currently maintain a public Java Web App that uses JSP, linux server.

I wish to create a new public Web App, but using a Javascript client, not JSP, and that the data for this client is provided by my Java Web Application.  A request is sent to the Web App from the Javascript Client and data comes back as JSON.

There is a requirement that it's not a **simple** matter for scrapers to download the million of records that the client visualises.

My ideal solution would be to use something similar to what google and bing  restrict the use of their mapping via the Javascript API's Keys system.  This would also allow me to provide API keys to trusted third parties.  How do they detect that the API key is valid for a particular domain, and that it's not been copied to another domain.

Does anyone have a different approach, or know of a system to enable API keys like google maps?

Comment: "that it's not been copied to another domain" - They can't in terms of preventing someone using the key in an application. Otherwise for browser-based, they ususally check the `Referer` header.

Comment: Ah, so every time I've previously had an issue with API keys I could have easily have used another API Key and faked the `Referer` header.  Thanks